# How do I place a button in an Android activity in a new location?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, adt

It's been a while since I worked on any android projects. I started a new project yesterday in the ADT that google now provides, but I'm having trouble editing the activity using the graphical interface. Every time I place an new button in the activity, its snaps to the top left corner. When I drag it to a different location, it always snaps back. I don't recall that this used to happen when I was using juno.

[image: Activity]

Comment: Use a `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Amre, if you have solved this problem, post an answer detailing how and the steps to implement it, then accept that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it was caused by using a FrameLayout, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html

I had to change the activity to RelativeLayout by editing the xml:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.project.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="181dp"
        android:text="Button" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

To change it from the the graphical interface, expand "layouts" on the left, then drag relative layout to the screen.